# Keep backward compatibility for a function when we need to return more values than before

Tags: python, function, return-value

I have a function that that currently returns two values, an int and a string, for example:

```
def myfunc():
    return 0, 'stringA'
```

This function is already in use in a lot of code, but I'd need to improve it so it returns three values, an int and two strings, for example:

```
def myfunc():
    return 0, 'stringA', 'stringB'
```

Of course, I'd like to keep compatibility with existing code, so returning the values like the above modified function will lead to a ValueError.

One solution would be to wrap the improved function into another function with the old name, so we call the initial function in existing code, and the new function in new code, for example:

```
def newmyfunc():
    return 0, 'A', 'B'

def myfunc():
    result1, result2, _ = newmyfunc()
    return result1, result2
```

As far as this solution works, I don't really find it elegant.

Is there a better way to achieve this goal?
Something like a polymorphic function which could return two or three values without having to modify existing code that uses the function?

Comment: You *could* have a function return different types based on its parameters, but that seems worse than making a new function.  If you make a new function, you can deprecate and eventually remove the old function by searching for places where it's used; if the new behavior is a flag then it's no longer a trivial search.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible, since my function is part of a pip package which is more widely used than just my own code

Comment: If this is used externally all the more reason to not change the contract of existing functions, and to make it easy for users to migrate to the new API.

Comment: "Something like a polymorphic function which could return two or three values without having to modify existing code that uses the function?" that sounds much worse than your `newmyfunc` solution, IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, answering a question you didn't ask, but which may help in the future or for other folks:

When I find that I'm returning multiple items from a single function, and especially when the list of items returned starts to grow, I often find it useful to return either a dict or an object rather than a tuple.  The reason is that as the returned-item list grows, it becomes harder to keep track of which item's at which index.  If the group of returned items are going to be used separately and aren't closely-related other than both coming from the same function, I prefer a dict.  If the returned items *are* being used together in multiple locations (e.g. user name, password, host & port), wrap them all in an object (instantiate a custom class), and just pass that around.  YMMV, and it sounds like you're trying to avoid refactoring the code, so:

The simplest solution to your actual question is to add a keyword argument to your function, set a default on that argument, and use it to decide which version of the arguments to return:

```
def myfunc(return_length=2):
    if return_length == 2:
        return 0, 'stringA'
    elif return_length == 3:
        return 0, 'stringA', 'stringB'
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Unexpected number of return arguments {return_length}')
```

Old code continues to call the function as-is, and new code explicitly calls `my_func(return_length=3)`.  At such point as all the old code gets deprecated, you can change the default value to 3 and/or throw an error when it's set to 2.

Comment: In my case, I have to return an exit code, stdout and stderr outputs (which were mixed before). So there's no logical reason for me to use a dict for returns. Anyway, using a new parameter like `separate_streams` which defaults to False could solve the issue, even if it's not what I am searching for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An example with decorators: the body of the involved functions stays untouched, the "modification"-part is delegated to an external function, *the decorator*.

Assumed "ground functions" take no arguments.

```
def dec(f_reference):
    return lambda f_extra_feature: lambda:(*f_reference(), f_extra_feature())

def myfunc():
    return 0, 'stringA'

def xxxfunc():
    return 'XXX'

myfunc = dec(f_reference=myfunc)(f_extra_feature=xxxfunc)

print(myfunc)
#(0, 'stringA', 'XXX')
```

Depending on the needs the second parameter, `f_extra_feature`, can be made implicit.

A less flexible decoration could be done with the syntactic sugar notation

```
# order of argument is changed!
def dec2(f_extra_feature):
    return lambda f_reference: lambda:(*f_reference(), f_extra_feature())

def xxxfunc():
    return 'XXX'

@dec2(f_extra_feature=xxxfunc)
def myfunc():
    return 0, 'stringA'

print(myfunc())
#(0, 'stringA', 'XXX')
```

EDIT:

```
def newmyfunc():
    return 0, 'A', 'B'

def replacer(f):
    return lambda f_target: lambda: f()[slice(0, 2)] 

@replacer(newmyfunc)
def myfunc():
    return 0, 'stringA'

# new body of the function, execute newmyfunc
print(myfunc())
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I need. I don't have two separate funxtions that I need to concatenate, just one that returns exit code + stdout or exit code + stdout + stderr from a subprocess call. Hence I cannot call two different functions for stdout and stderr.

Comment: @Orsiris de Jong I edited the answer and the decorator perform a full substitution of the body of the original function

Comment: Elegant solution, just not what I need for my purposed. Truly appreciate the effort though. Thank you.